# PHP, how do I pass variables between methods?

Tags: php, class, methods

I'm trying to pass a variable from one method to another.

I'm fetching dates from an events table in order to build a dynamic query in another method.

```
class Player extends Database {
    private $start_date;
    private $end_date;
    private $sumCase;

protected function getEvents() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `events`";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $event_arr = array();
        foreach($results as $result) {
            $event_name = $result['event_name'];
            $this->start_date = $result['start_date'];
            $this->end_date = $result['end_date'];

            $this->sumCase[] = "SUM(CASE WHEN date BETWEEN $this->start_date AND $this->end_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '$event_name'";
            $dateBetween[] = "date BETWEEN $this->start_date AND $this->end_date";
            array_push($event_arr, array(
                "name" => $result['event_name'],
                "start" => $result['start_date'],
                "end" => $result['end_date'],
            ));
        }
        return print_r($this->sumCase);
    }
```

this returns my sumCase array without problems, I'm now trying to access this sumCase array in another method in order to build the query:

```
protected function getPlayerEvents() {
        $sql = "SELECT count(chalID) as total, ";
        $sql .=' '.implode(', ', $this->sumCase); 
        $sql .="from (SELECT * FROM times where ("; //ignore this
        $sql .="date BETWEEN 159310659 AND 1593538594  OR date BETWEEN 1693538594 AND 1793538594"; //ignore this
        $sql .=") AND plaID = 1 group by chalID) A"; //ignore this

        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
        echo $this->sumCase; //returns null, how do I pass variables between methods?
    }
```

when I echo my sumCase array within this method, it returns null. How do I access the value of the sumCase array from the getEvents method?

Comment: Did you intend to make `$sumCase` into an array when you assign it a value, with the square brackets? That would affect your ability to echo it.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and include that in your question. Also note that it's unclear why you store this in a member and return its content formatted with `print_r()`. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Are you using $sumCase variable in the same object context  for calling in the both function ?

Comment: @MartinZeitler ya, the questioner has not clear everything in his query

Comment: There is no need to `return` anything, when using a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns null if function getEvents wasnt called first or it was called not to same instance of object.

```
<?php

use directory_with_classes\Player;

$player = new Player();
$player->getEvents();
$player->getPlayerEvents();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your problem, you need to access a variable in a method declared in another one. In order to carry the variable over, you need to first declare the $ globally and then access it inside the functions.
Example:

```
    $foo = NULL; // Placeholder
    function seg() {
        $foo = "something";
    }
    function bar() {
        echo $foo; // You can now access it!
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is sequential code at the global scope, while the topic is OOP.

Answer (score 0):

```
function __construct(){
  $this->foo = "";
}

function seg() {
  $this->foo = "something";
}

function bar() {
  echo $this->foo; // You can now access it!
}
```